# Feed a trainable variable into a placeholder in TensorFlow

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow, placeholder

Suppose I want to train a model over a number of samples (and also variables) that are **known only at run time**.

## Case study: PCA (X W = Y)

[image: Valid XHTML]

(this is only a simplification of a much more complex model)

Take for example this simple PCA model, where only the features dimensions (Din and Dout) are known and fixed.

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([D_in, D_out]), name='weights', trainable=True)
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, D_in], name='placeholder_latent')

Y_est = tf.matmul(X, W)
loss = tf.reduce_sum((Y_tf-Y_est)**2)

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)
```

Suppose now we generate some data

```
W_true = np.random.randn(D_in, D_out)
X_true = np.random.randn(N, D_in)
Y_true = np.dot(X_true, W_true)
Y_tf = tf.constant(Y_true.astype(np.float32))
```

As soon as I know the dimension of my training data, I can declare the `latent` variable that will be fed to the placeholder `X` to be optimised.

```
latent = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([N, D_in]), name='latent', trainable=True)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

After that, what I would like to do is to feed this `latent` variable to the placeholder `X` and run the optimisation.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  for n in range(10000):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={X : sess.run(latent)})
    if (n+1) % 1000 == 0:
      print('iter %i, %f' % (n+1, sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X : sess.run(latent)})))
```

The problem is that the optimiser does not optimise `W` and `latent`, but only `W`. I have tried also to feed the variable directly without evaluation but I get this error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Have you ever encountered this kind of issue? Do you know how to overcome this problem? Are there any possible workaround to optimise on a placeholder?

By the way, I am using `TensorFlow 1.1.0rc0` with `Python 2.7.13`

Comment: If you use latent as your input, how would it be optimised...?

Comment: You defined your loss function as 'Y_est = tf.matmul(X, W);
loss = tf.reduce_sum((Y_tf-Y_est)**2)'. So latent is not participated in the model and it would not be optimized.

Comment: @S.Stas what do you mean for "latent is not participated in the model"?  X is simply a placeholder which is fed by latent

Comment: It means that basically you are trying to find W that solves the equation XW = Y, such that a loss function f(Y - Y_true) will be minimised. So f, the loss, depends on X and W. However, since X is your input (i.e. observed/collected data), to minimise the loss you take gradient of f by the independent variable W - not by X. Since in your case X is some function of latent X = g(latent), to ask the algorithm for an optimised X - or latent - is contradicting the equation you are solving.